# Creating routes completely offline - osmdroid

Tags: plugins, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid and I'm creating routes but completely offline.
I wanted to know if there's any plugin that identifies crossroads, etc or do I have to do that manually ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at OSMbonusPack, might be helpful. http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/